# Why is Ansible using a previously created host?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm working on a simple ansible playbook to create a temporary EC2 instance. The first time I ran the playbook I received this recap -

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.31.14.136              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

After it ran I realized I wanted to tweak something so I made the minor change (unrelated to hosts) and ran it again and got this recap -

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.31.13.74               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
172.31.14.136              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

My playbook is very simple and should only contain two hosts - my localhost and the ip of the newly created EC2 instance. Here is the playbook -

```
- name: Provision instance
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/test_ec2.yml

  roles:
    - { role: ec2_create, product: "tmp_instance_test" }

- name: Configure SSH Authorized Keys
  hosts: tmp_instance_test
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/test_ec2.yml

  roles:
    - { role: yarn }
```

My question is why is it that the ip from the first run `172.31.14.136` was involved in the second run?

---

*Update*

Here is the role `ec2_create` -

```
- name: Create instance
  ec2:
    image: "{{ image }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key_id }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    instance_tags:
      Name: "{{ name }}"
      Environment: "{{ env }}"
      Product: "{{ product }}"
      Service: "{{ service }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: "{{ disk_name }}"
        volume_type: "{{ disk_type }}"
        volume_size: "{{ disk_size }}"
        delete_on_termination: "{{ delete_on_termination }}"
    group: "{{ security_group_name }}"
    wait: true
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc_subnet_id }}"
    count: "{{ instance_count }}"
    monitoring: "{{ detailed_monitoring }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ iam_role }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ assign_public_ip }}"
  register: ec2

- name: Wait for SSH to come up
  wait_for: host={{ item.private_ip }} port=22 timeout=600 state=started
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: refresh inventory
  meta: refresh_inventory
```

---

*Update 2*

Inventory -

```
[localhost]
localhost ansible_ssh_user=deployer ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python

[tag_Product_tmp_instance_test]
[tmp_instance_test:children]
tag_Product_tmp_instance_test
[tmp_instance_test:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu 
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/BaseDev
```

Comment: Who knows what's inside `ec2_create` role?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I updated the question with the ec2_create role

Comment: And another guess: you use dynamic inventory generated by something like `ec2.py`?

Comment: I am using dynamic inventory and updated my question. Would this maybe be a caching issue? Also this only seems to happen when I run it immediately after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `meta: refresh_inventory` you force inventory update, and if the previous server (`172.31.14.136` in your example) is still alive in your AWS account it gets matched by your search criteria (`tag_Product_tmp_instance_test`) thus belongs to `tmp_instance_test` group.

So if you don't terminate hosts created by `ec2_create` role, all of them will appear in your inventory on subsequent playbook runs.

Comment: Just took a look at the cache and saw this, this is exactly what is happening. Thank you.